# Conceptual explanation of geometric mean as a limit of power means

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be positive real numbers and $p\in\mathbb{R}
-\{0\}$. The *power mean* $M_p(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ of exponent $p$ is
defined by
  $$ M_p(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\left( \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p
      \right)^{1/p}. $$
By taking logarithms and applying L'Hôpital's rule (or just the
definition of a derivative), we get
  $$ \lim_{p\to 0} M_p(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n}, $$
the geometric mean of $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Thus the "correct"
definition of $M_0$ is $M_0(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots
x_n}$. All this is well known, but I am wondering if there is some
conceptual explanation, not involving computation, for the value of
$M_0(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

Comment: Small, not really conceptual comment: suppose we allow some $x_i$ to be $0$ as well; then $\lim_{p\to \infty}M_p$ is totally insensitive to having a single value of $x_i$ equal to zero; whereas the ``opposite'' limit $\lim_{p\to 0}M_p$ is "totally sensitive" to a single zero value.

Comment: Unrelated to your nice post (if it is required I can delete this comment), is that I tried in recent months and weeks write variations of certain unsolved problems using combinations with certain means, for example the more recent is the post with title *On variations of a claim due to Kaneko in terms of Lehmer means* of Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: I mean, we can define $M_p$ as the unique solution $\mu$ to $\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{x_i}^\mu y^{p-1} dy = 0$ and then for $p=0$ we get the geometric mean.

Comment: In case no one has thought of this, a trivial observation that lets you guess the value of $M_0$ immediately with no calculation is that as $p$ approaches $0$ the $x_i^p$'s get closer and closer to 1 and the inequality $M_p\geq GM$ moves towards its condition of equality (from AM-GM applied to the $x_i^p$'s).

Answer (score 6):

$(\frac{a^{1/n} + b^{1/n}}{2})^n$ has normalized symmetric binomial (i.e., close to normal) distribution of coefficients convolved with some bounded expressions in $a$ and $b$ (of the form $a^\theta b^{1 - \theta}$).   The normal distribution is sharply peaked around its mean so you end up with the middle terms with $\theta = 1/2$ in the limit of large $n$.  This generalizes to more variables and weights.

That is still a calculation, but one where the answer is easy to foresee at the outset and the idea can be explained in a few words.

Answer (score 3):

A reasonably intuitive way to "see" that the limit must be the geometric mean is the plausible and useful observation that any power mean can be expressed in terms of the midpoint means, $M_p(x,y)=((x^p+y^p)/2)^{1/p}$, recursively if the number of variables is not a power of 2. See my [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/347499/7113) to a related question.

Simple algebra then proves that for $n=2$, and all $p\neq0$, $M_p M_{-p}=x_1x_2$ so letting $p\rightarrow0$ we have $M_0^2=x_1x_2$ and the general limit value follows immediately.

Note that this doesn't use calculus, transcendental functions, or in fact anything other than the power means themselves and their continuity.

**Update:**

A further low tech way to see the result uses functional equations.

We simply note that the power means satisfy $$M_{rp}(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=M_p(x_1^r,\cdots,x_n^r)^{1/r}.$$

Setting $p=0$ gives

$$M_{0}(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=M_0(x_1^r,\cdots,x_n^r)^{1/r}$$ for all $r\in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}.$

Then it is intuitively clear since $M$ is symmetric and $M_p(\lambda \mathbb x)=\lambda M_p(\mathbb x)$ that $M_0$ must be the geometric mean.

You can prove this formally by induction starting with $n=2$. Let $f(x)=M_0(x,1)=f(x^r)^{1/r}$, by the above. Then setting $x=e$, $r=\log X$ we have  $f(X)=f(e)^{\log X}=X^{\log f(e)}=x^\mu$ where $\mu$ is constant.

Hence $M_0(x,y)=yM_0(x/y,1)=yf(x/y)=y(x/y)^\mu=y^{1-\mu}x^{\mu}$. SInce $M_0$ is symmetric in $x$ and $y$ we have $\mu=1/2$ and $M_0(x,y)=x^{1/2}y^{1/2}$. The other cases $n>2$ follow in a similar manner.

**Further update:**

Actually probably the most intuitive way is just to note, as Iosif did as well, that AM-GM or Jensen's inequality tells you $M_p\geq GM\geq M_{-p}$. Then just take the limit as $p\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Concerning your Update: When you say "Setting $p=0$", you set $p=0$ in an identity which you assume to hold only for $p\ne0$, right? Concerning your Further update: Did you notice that using the AGM/Jensen inequality is what had been done in my answer? After that, the main problem was to "just take the limit as $p\to0$". Well, that was the problem stated in the OP from the very beginning.

Comment: @IosifPinelis In my answers I was more concerned with explaining the value since that was requested by the OP - "I am wondering if there is some conceptual explanation...for the value of $M_0$" So when I say "setting $p=0$" I am assuming the limit exists. Yes I did notice after I added my further update that you had used the AGM inequalities - again I assumed the limit exists.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\o\overline$
This proof uses only the arithmetic-geometric mean (AGM) inequality and the fact that for any smooth even function $g\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ we have $g'(0)=0$.

To simplify the writing, for any function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ let 
$$\o{f(x)}:=\frac1n\,\sum_1^n f(x_i).$$

We have to show that 
$$M_p:=(\o{x^p})^{1/p}\to M_0:=\exp\,\o{\ln x}$$
as $p\to0$.

Take any real $p>0$. Replacing the $x_i$'s in the AGM inequality 
$$\o x\ge \exp\,\o{\ln x} \tag{1}$$
by the $x_i^p$'s, we have $M_p\ge M_0$. Similarly, replacing the $x_i$'s in (1) by the $x_i^{-p}$'s, we have $M_{-p}\le M_0$. So, 
$$M_{-p}\le M_0\le M_p.$$
It remains to show that $M_p/M_{-p}\to1$ as $p\downarrow0$ or, equivalently, that 
$$g(p):=\ln\o{x^p}+\ln\o{x^{-p}}=o(p),$$
which follows because the function $g$ is smooth and even, with $g(0)=0$. $\Box$

---

The expression $\exp\,\o{\ln x}\,[=(x_1\cdots x_n)^{1/n}]$ for the geometric mean arises naturally, as an instance, with $f=\exp$, of the more general mean of the form $f\big(\o{f^{-1}(x)}\big)$ with a continuous increasing function $f$. So, the geometric mean is just a logarithmically/exponentially re-scaled version of the arithmetic mean. 
Also, the AGM inequality (1) is an instance of Jensen's inequality for the concave function $\ln$ or, equivalently, for the the convex function $\exp$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the following is a conceptual explanation rather than a calculation:

Writing $x_i=e^{u_i}$ and letting $p\to0$, we have 
$$M_p=\Big(\frac1n\,\sum_1^n e^{pu_i}\Big)^{1/p}
=\Big(1+\frac p{n+o(1)}\,\sum_1^n u_i\Big)^{1/p}\to\exp\Big(\frac1n\,\sum_1^n u_i\Big)=M_0,$$
where $M_r:=M_r(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

(I guess in any case we need to show that $M_p\to M_0$ as $p\to0$. Here, at least we do not explicitly use the l'Hospital rule or differentiation.)